# Constructor of type missing - Adding to a generic array with generic method

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, types, casting

I'm trying to create an array of generic classes as follows below, however, I'm running into trouble. The first problem is an error "MissingMethodException: Constructor of type Dog not found" when the AddGenericComponent method is called. This method should add whatever class is thrown into it to the components array and also return that component that was just added to be modified in a way similar to as seen "Test()". Does anyone have a suggestion or solution on how to do this?

```
public void Test()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    Dog dog = myClass.AddGenericComponent<Dog>();
    dog.name = "Fluffy";
    Console.Writeline(dog.name);
    //testing the accessor
    dog = myClass.GetGenericComponent<Dog>();
    dog.name = "Fluffy mod";
    Console.Writeline(dog.name);
}


public class MyClass
{
   //must be an array, not list
   GenericComponent<Object>[] components = new GenericComponent<Object>[1];
   public T AddGenericComponent<T>()
   {
       GenericComponent<Object>[] newArray = new GenericComponent<Object>[components.Length + 1];
       components.CopyTo(newArray, 0);
       components = newArray;
       components[components.Length - 1] = new GenericComponent<Object>();
       return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new GenericComponent<Object> { });
   }
   public T GetGenericComponent<T>()
   {
      return (T)Array.Find(components, c => c.GetType() == typeof(T)).component;
   }
}

public class GenericComponent<T> where T: new()
{
   public T component;
   public GenericComponent()
   {
       component = new T();
   }
}

public class Dog
{
   public string name = "";
   public Dog(){}
   public Dog(string name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

}
```

Edit:

I think I've solved it.

```
 public T AddGenericComponent<T>()
 {
    GenericComponent<Object>[] newArray = new GenericComponent<Object>[components.Length + 1];
    components.CopyTo(newArray, 0);
    components = newArray;
    GenericComponent<Object> newComponent = new GenericComponent<Object>();//;(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    newComponent.component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    components[components.Length - 1] = newComponent;
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

```
class Test
{
    public void TestStart()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Dog dog = myClass.AddGenericComponent<Dog>();
        dog.name = "Fluffy";
        Console.Writeline(dog.name);
        //testing the accessor
        dog = myClass.GetGenericComponent<Dog>();
        dog.name = "Fluffy mod";
        Console.Writeline(dog.name);
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class GameObject
{
    List<GenericComponent<Object>> componentList = new List<GenericComponent<Object>>();

    //returns first found in list.
    public T GetComponent<T>()
    {
        return (T)componentList.Find(c => c.component.GetType() == typeof(T)).component;
    }
    //add a component to component list.
    public T AddComponent<T>()
    {
        GenericComponent<Object> newComponent = new GenericComponent<Object>();
        newComponent.component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        componentList.Add(newComponent);
        return (T)newComponent.component;
    }
    //returns all components of type T
    public List<T> GetComponents<T>()
    {
        List<T> r = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < componentList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (componentList[i].component.GetType() == typeof(T))
            {
                r.Add((T)componentList[i].component);
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class GenericComponent<T> where T : new()
{
    public T component;
    public GenericComponent()
    {
        component = new T();
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class Dog
{
    public string name = "";
    public Dog() { }
    public Dog(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you tried to do here but:

```
public static object CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args);
```

The `args` are the ctor params.

`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Dog));` -> this will invoke the `public Dog(){}` ctor.

`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Dog),"myString");` -> this will invoke the `public Dog(string name){}` ctor.

`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new GenericComponent<Object> { });` -> this will invoke the `public Dog(GenericComponent<Object> param){}` ctor that **doesnt exist** and therefore you get the **exception**.

**Edit:**
I tried to understand why you did what you did but couldn't. Anyway it looks like you wanted something like this:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Dog dog = myClass.AddGenericComponent<Dog>();
        dog.name = "Fluffy";
        MessageBox.Show(dog.name);
        //testing the accessor - ADD a NULL CHECK!!!
        dog = myClass.GetGenericComponent<Dog>();
        dog.name = "Fluffy mod";
        MessageBox.Show(dog.name);
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();

        public T AddGenericComponent<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            T obj = GetGenericComponent<T>();

            if (obj == null)
            {
                obj = new T();
                objects.Add(obj);
            }

            return obj;
        }

        public T GetGenericComponent<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            var relevantObj = objects.FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetType() == typeof(T));
            if (relevantObj != null)
            {
                return relevantObj as T;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Dog
    {
        public string name = "";
        public Dog() { }
        public Dog(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've got it working but one other question, do you know how I might create a method something along the lines of: "public T[] GetComponents<T>()
        { return (T[])Array.FindAll(components, c => c.component.GetType() == typeof(T));
        }"?  I keep getting cannot convert type error.